# VS2017 not deploying everything to AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a VS2017 solution (asp.net core 2.1). actually I have several.
But for one of the UI projects when I deploy to the AWS EC2 instance it deploys everything except for one directory.

If I manually copy the missing directory to the EC2 instance everything works.

I've not seen this behaviour before - has anyone come across this or can anyone suggest where I can start looking?

Thanks,
P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the grounds that no-one could answer this I'm assuming that this is not a regular problem.

So for the benefit of everyone, here's the solution.

For a .Net Core 2.1 solution - in the file .csproj we have a list of items that will be deployed and folders

if you have an additional folder outside of the wwwroot folder that you would like to deploy as part of your solution you need to add the following line:

```
<Content Include="<foldername>\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />


<foldername> is the name and location of your folder and ** denotes everything in the folder including subfolders.
```

I hope that this helps someone other than me.

Paul.